# can jsoup handle meta refresh redirect

Tags: java, jsoup

I have a problem using jsoup what I am trying to do is fetch a document from the url which will redirect to another url based on meta refresh url which is not working, to explain clearly if I am entering a website url named http://www.amerisourcebergendrug.com which will automatically redirect to http://www.amerisourcebergendrug.com/abcdrug/ depending upon the meta refresh url but my jsoup is still sticking with http://www.amerisourcebergendrug.com and not redirecting and fetching from http://www.amerisourcebergendrug.com/abcdrug/

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.amerisourcebergendrug.com").get();
```

I have also tried using,

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.amerisourcebergendrug.com").followRedirects(true).get();
```

but both are not working

Any workaround for this?

**Update:**
The Page may use meta refresh redirect methods

Comment: It is possible that server is returning incorrect status for redirects. If it is possible add real url, so people can test if server response is correct.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Update (case insensitive and pretty fault tolerant)

- The content parsed (almost) according to [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/meta.http-equiv.refresh.html)
- The [first successfully parsed content meta data](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#attr-meta-http-equiv-refresh) should be used

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    URI uri = URI.create("http://www.amerisourcebergendrug.com");

    Document d = Jsoup.connect(uri.toString()).get();

    for (Element refresh : d.select("html head meta[http-equiv=refresh]")) {

        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?si)\\d+;\\s*url=(.+)|\\d+")
                           .matcher(refresh.attr("content"));

        // find the first one that is valid
        if (m.matches()) {
            if (m.group(1) != null)
                d = Jsoup.connect(uri.resolve(m.group(1)).toString()).get();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs correctly:

```
http://www.amerisourcebergendrug.com/abcdrug/
```

---

### Old answer:

Are you sure that it isn't working. For me:

```
System.out.println(Jsoup.connect("http://www.ibm.com").get().baseUri());
```

.. outputs `http://www.ibm.com/us/en/` correctly..

Comment: sorry its working for redirect urls but not following the meta refresh urls. I have updated my question with such kind of website

Comment: Ok, well jsoup doesn't seem to work with meta-redirects, I update my answer with some code that can handle such redirects.

Comment: Yeah I know we can select the meta tag and extract but I thought jsoup will handle this automatically and its now clear it wont handle. Really thanks for making me clear.

Comment: You should use `.split("=", 2)`. Otherwise, the match will fail if the redirect target contains an `=` (e.g. in the querystring).

Comment: `REFRESH` can also be written as `refresh`. It would thus be safer to check for `meta.attr("http-equiv").toUpperCase().contains("REFRESH")`

Comment: Thanks Bob and @f_puras. Updated this answer with both case insensitive  refresh and url. Also handling faulty content strings.

Comment: @dacwe the space between the semicolon is unnecessary and will fail in some cases like the following: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://abstrusegoose.com/288">`

Answer (score 3):

to have a better error handling and case sensitivity problem

```
try
{
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.ibm.com").get();
    Elements meta = doc.select("html head meta");
    if (meta != null)
    {
        String lvHttpEquiv = meta.attr("http-equiv");
        if (lvHttpEquiv != null && lvHttpEquiv.toLowerCase().contains("refresh"))
        {
            String lvContent = meta.attr("content");
            if (lvContent != null)
            {
                String[] lvContentArray = lvContent.split("=");
                if (lvContentArray.length > 1)
                    doc = Jsoup.connect(lvContentArray[1]).get();
            }
        }
    }

    // get page title
    return doc.title();

}
catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```