# JSOUP HTML parsing from URL

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I'm using JSOUP in Java to parse HTMLs like these two:
[This](http://auto.sme.sk/c/8032434/mercedes-predviedol-v-premavke-seriovy-kamion-s-autonomnym-riadenim.html) and [this](http://ekonomika.sme.sk/c/8047766/s-velkymi-chybami-stavali-aj-budovu-centralnej-banky.html).

In the first case, I get the output.

And I have a problem with the connection:

```
doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
```

There are some URLs which can easily be parsed, and I've got the output, but there are URLs too which produces empty output like this:

```
Title: [].
```

I can't understand what the problem is if both URLs are the same.
This is my code:

```
Document doc;

try {
   doc = Jsoup.connect("http://ekonomika.sme.sk/c/8047766/s-velkymi-chybami-stavali-aj-budovu-centralnej-banky.html").get();
   String title = doc.title();
   System.out.println("title : " + title);      
} 
catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Do the pages have a title?

Comment: Yes, all they got a tittle like > s-velkymi-chybami-stavali-aj-budovu-centralnej-banky, sorry for the language it's Slovak. But www.sme.sk is a Slovak html page, where people can read article's neary about everything. Ande ekonomika is a tittle of a kategory within the page... there are categories also like Cars, Culture and so one.

Comment: The stacktrace? Otherwise we won't know what's you error

Comment: Well, considering that JSoup is extremely good at parsing HTML, it's weird that it wouldn't be able to parse something as simple as the title. @YummyUnicornRainbowTails There's no stacktrace involved.

Comment: `document.select("title").text()`

Comment: I don't have error output... the program is running well... but in some cases for some URLs the output is simply empty.

Comment: Yes im'using select to, for example doc.select("span[class^=autor]"), when i wanted to get the name of author for articles. But no result.

Comment: Create a minimal example with a real URL that fails together with your code of how you try to access it. Then we may be able to see what the problem is. Without this, it is more or less guesswork. There are several things that can prevent Jsoup from loading the content. Among those are: Try to access dynamic content, wrong user-agent, too short timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at what's in the head of the second url

```
Element h = doc.head();
System.out.println("head : " + h);
```

You'll see there are some meta refresh tags and an empty title:

```
<head> 

 <noscript> 
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;URL='/c/8047766/s-velkymi-chybami-stavali-aj-budovu-centralnej-banky.html?piano_d=1'"> 
 </noscript> 

 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10;URL='/c/8047766/s-velkymi-chybami-stavali-aj-budovu-centralnej-banky.html?piano_t=1'"> 

 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 

 <title></title> 

</head>
```

Which explains the empty title. You have to follow the redirect.

Comment: BTW to have JSoup follow the meta refresh redirect, this answer may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343974/can-jsoup-handle-meta-refresh-redirect. AFAIK JSoup's `followRedirects` can only be used for http header redirects. To follow meta refresh redirects you have to pry out the url from the meta tag yourself.

Comment: BTW2 If you get a 403 add a user-agent: `.userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0")`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code for parsing, with this URL I have no output.
    /*
     * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
     * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */
    package commentparser;

```
import java.io.IOException;
import static java.lang.Boolean.FALSE;
import static java.lang.Boolean.TRUE;
import java.net.URL;
import static java.sql.JDBCType.NULL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import static javafx.beans.binding.Bindings.length;
import static jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.ArrayBufferView.length;
import static oracle.jrockit.jfr.events.Bits.length;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class CommentParser {

  public static void main(String[] args) {


    Document doc;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://ekonomika.sme.sk/c/8047766/s-velkymi-chybami-stavali-aj-budovu-centralnej-banky.html").followRedirects(true).get();

        String title = doc.title();       
        System.out.println("title : " + title); 
        //Link for discussions  
                if(doc.select("a[href^=/diskusie/reaction_show]").isEmpty() == FALSE){
                   Elements description = doc.select("a[href^=/diskusie/reaction_show]");
                    for (Element link : description) {
                        // get the value from href attribute
                        System.out.println("Diskusie: " + link.attr("href"));
                    }
                }
                //Author of article
                if(doc.select("span[class^=autor]").isEmpty() == FALSE){
                   Elements description = doc.select("span[class^=autor]");
                    for (Element link : description) {
                        // get the value from href attribute
                        //System.out.println("\nlink : " + link.attr("b"));
                        System.out.println(link.text());
                    }
                }
        // get all links
        Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
        for (Element link : links) {

            // get the value from href attribute
            System.out.println("\nlink : " + link.attr("href"));
            System.out.println("text : " + link.text());

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: See my answer, as soon as you append `?piano_d=1` to the url I get all the desired output. But as I stated in a comment, using `followRedirects(true)` will not bring you to this url, since `followRedirects` only works on server redirects. So you have to parse the meta refresh tag yourself as shown in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343974/can-jsoup-handle-meta-refresh-redirect