# HTML body returns empty (most of it) when calling from Jsoup

Tags: java, android, html, jsoup

i have a page im trying to get its `HTML`. Before i was able to get the `HTML` and select an element, today they somehow changed something which made it return `null` when calling from a mobile.

The thing is, when you open from the browser and inspect the page, the whole HTML shows up, but when calling from mobile, its different.

Code:

```
Connection.Response response= Jsoup.connect(mStreamLinkString)
    .ignoreContentType(true)
    .header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0")
    .referrer("http://www.twitter.com")
    .maxBodySize(0)
    .timeout(600000)
    .followRedirects(true)
    .execute();
Document html =  response.parse();
String First = html.html();
Log.i("HTML",First);
```

Output:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta name="referrer" content="always">
  <noscript>
   <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://kad71.com/C20/H/M">
  </noscript>
  <title>http://kad71.com/C20/H/M</title>
  <script>window.opener = null; location.replace("http:\/\/kad71.com\/C20\/H\/M")</script>
 </head>
 <body></body>
</html>
```

Example link:

http://kad71.com/C20/H/M

Comment: I'm afraid you will need to implement a client side redirect like this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/7347547/1997376

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot! **Can you post it as an answer?

Comment: thx for proposing but it is not my answer, simply consider upvoting the answer that I shared instead