# Get content of a webpage which is redirected to another webpage

Tags: java, jsoup, crawler4j

I want to crawl the content of the webpage - http://www.pgmfi.org/. But if we visit the page, we will see it redirects to the page - http://twiki.pgmfi.org/bin/view.

When I tried to crawl the content from the URL (http://www.pgmfi.org/) using `jsoup` or `crawler4j`, I got the following content.

```
Looking for PGMFI.ORG Home ? Please wait redirecting to: http://twiki.pgmfi.org
```

But I want to get more information about the webpage from that redirected webpage (http://twiki.pgmfi.org/bin/view). When I run a simple code using `jsoup`, I found the following.

```
String url = "http://www.pgmfi.org/";

Response response = Jsoup.connect(url).followRedirects(false).execute();
System.out.println(response.statusCode() + " : " + response.url());

//check if URL is redirect?
System.out.println("Is URL going to redirect : " + response.hasHeader("location"));
System.out.println("Target : " + response.header("location"));
```

Output:

```
200 : http://www.pgmfi.org/
Is URL going to redirect : false
Target : null
```

So, the redirection is obviously not straight-forward. My question - is there any way, I can get the url to which the page is redirecting without parsing the html body?

I prefer a solution using `crawler4j`. Even a solution in `jsoup` is fine for me.

Comment: You need to figure out whether or how your scraping library supports a meta-refresh based redirect. If not, either parse it out yourself or start your crawl at http://twiki.pgmfi.org.

Comment: I don't know why I got downvote. I tried different alternatives before asking this question on SO but failed. I need to crawl the redirected page from the original url, so right now I am not considering crawling directly from the redirected url.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. Perhaps you're unfamiliar with the type of redirect? It's, strictly speaking, not a redirect and is dependent on parsing the HTML.

Comment: @pvg I agree with your point. its not a straight redirect, I understand. I can definitely try by parsing the HTML but before that I want to make sure if there is any other way around except parsing the content of the page, get the url and then crawl the content from that url.

Comment: Google meta refresh and crawler4j, it looks like there have been attempts to fix this.

Comment: This question has a way to do it with jsoup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343974/can-jsoup-handle-meta-refresh-redirect

Comment: `crawler4j` does not support extracting URLs from meta-refresh. You have access to the meta-tags in `crawler4j`, but you would need to find a way to add the extracted URL to the frontier ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`crawler4j` does not support extracting URLs from `meta-refresh`. However, `crawler4j` provides the respective meta-tags (see [`HTMLParseData`](https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j/blob/master/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/parser/HtmlParseData.java)), so you could enhance the `visit(...)` method to add the extracted URL to the `Frontier` object in `WebCrawler` via `schedule(...)`.

However, `Frontier` has only `private` access in `WebCrawler` and is therefore not available for your concrete sub-class. For modifying this, youl would either need to (a) fork it or (b) use the Reflection API to change the access modifier.

Another way would be to open an issue on the official issue tracker [here](https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j).